# Rails Authority gem, trouble with 'show' action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authority-gem

It's the first time I'm using this gem and it's driving me crazy with something as simple as authorize the `show`action only for the resource owner.

I tried different ways, configuring the controller mapping and actions, but always get the unauthorized message for `show`, other actions work as they should.

It seems that `show`is not getting it's way to the ApplicationAuthorizer.

This is how it's configured:

```
class EnterpriseAuthorizer < ApplicationAuthorizer
  # This works
  def self.creatable_by?(user)
    user.is_enterpriser?
  end
  # This doesn't
  def readable_by?(user)
    true # Just for testing
  end 
end

class EnterprisesController < ApplicationController
  authorize_actions_for Enterprise
  def show
   @enterprise = Enterprise.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @enterprise }
     end
 end
```

I have `include Authority::UserAbilities` in User and `include Authority::Abilities` in the Enterprise model. And User `has_one :enterprise`

Any idea? Thinking seriously about rolling back to cancan.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: class vs instance methods?

Comment: I think that show should be an instance method, it shouldn't be possible to check the resource owner in other way.

Comment: I think you're getting unauthorized for `show` because you haven't defined `self.readable_by?` on the authorizer, so it's falling back to `self.default`, which returns false unless you redefine it. The before-filter created by `authorize_actions_for` does its job before you find a model instance, so it does a class-level check: can this user ever read any Enterprise? If you then need to check this specific one, you do `authorize_action_for(@enterprise)` within the controller action, which uses the authorizer's instance method `readable_by?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authority has different ways of checking permissions. For collection-based actions (e.g. new, create, index), you use `authorize_actions_for Model`.

For instance-based actions (e.g. edit, update, show, delete), you must call `authorize_action_for @instance`.

Change your code to this and it should work.

```
class EnterprisesController < ApplicationController
  authorize_actions_for Enterprise
  def show
    @enterprise = Enterprise.find(params[:id])
    authorize_action_for @enterprise
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @enterprise }
    end
  end
end
```

If you want a less messy way to do this, put the

```
@enterprise = Enterprise.find(params[:id])
authorize_action_for @enterprise
```

into a before filter that's called by each instance action.